# To increase height of my banner

Tags: jquery, angularjs

How can I increase the height of the banner on click of 
After clicking again it should go to less mode.

Comment: Code snippet is not working, or I should say it has nothing. Please let us us know what have you tried yet.

Comment: You can use jquery `toggle`

Answer (score 1):

You can make `.sqBan` `display:none;` and use `show()` and `hide()` in jQuery, or use `toggle()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.moreBan').click(function(){
    $('.sqBan').toggleClass('expand');
  });
});
```

```css
.sqBan {height:50px;background:indianred;transition:height .3s linear;}
.sqBan.expand {height:250px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='moreBan'>Click</div>
<div class='sqBan'>Some information here</div>
```

Comment: If I add "$('.sqBan').toggle();" My banner height wouldn't get increased..!

Comment: The banner itself disappearing

Comment: My wish is to have more mode and less mode for my banner

Answer (score 0):

Define a CSS class which sets the larger height and then use `toggleClass()` to turn it on and off. Try this:

```js
$('.moreBan').click(function() {
  $('.sqBan').toggleClass('large');
});
```

```css
.sqBan {
  background-color: #C00;
}
.large {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sqBan">sqBan...</div>
<div class="moreBan">Click me</div>
```